# How to run a NOT EXISTS query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections `page` and `likes`. In both collections there are field `pageId`. `likes` also has field `userName`.

If `likes` collection contains a pair `pageId`/`userName`, it means that the page was like by a particular user.

How can I run a query, which returns any one page, which was not liked by a particular user?

In SQL this would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM page
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'a' FROM likes WHERE (likes.pageId = page.pageId) AND (likes.userName = 'userName'))
LIMIT 1
```

I thought about using the `$exists` operator but [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) I've read that its meaning is different from the SQL operation with the same name and I have to use the `$in` operator.

I could

1. find out all pages, which a particular user liked and save them in a list and
2. then run a query on `page`, which should return the firt page, which is not contained in the list.

I'm hesitating to implement it this way because it seems very inefficient to me (I need only one page in step 2, but to get that one page I need to traverse all likes of the user).

Comment: Could you include an example of your data?  (A single record should suffice.)  It's pretty easy to use $exists to check for non-existence, but it all comes down to how your data is set up.

Answer (score 5):

In version 3.6, we have a new $lookup pipeline syntax that allows you to execute pipelines on related documents. You can use this to find related documents meeting your specific conditions. Combine this with a few more steps and you can construct a NOT EXISTS query.

1. Lookup related objects
2. Use `$expr { $and: [] }` to combine the join with additional constraints
3. Use `$limit: 1` to optimize, since we only care if one exists
4. `$match` where the join property `$exists: false`
5. For good measure, `$project` to eliminate the empty collection

For example, to query for pages with no likes by a particular user, construct your pipeline as follows:

```
db.page.insertOne({ pageId: 1 })
db.page.insertOne({ pageId: 2 })
db.page.insertOne({ pageId: 3 })
db.likes.insertOne({ pageId: 1, userName: "Pinky" })
db.likes.insertOne({ pageId: 2, userName: "Pinky" })
db.likes.insertOne({ pageId: 2, userName: "Brain" })
db.likes.insertOne({ pageId: 3, userName: "Brain" })

db.page.aggregate([{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "likes",
        "let": {
            "pageId": "$pageId"
        },
        "pipeline": [{
            "$match": {
                "$expr": {
                    "$and": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$pageId", "$$pageId" ] },
                        { "$eq": [ "$userName", "Pinky" ] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$limit": 1
        }],
        "as": "likes"
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "likes.pageId": { "$exists": false }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "likes": false
    }
}])
```

Comment: Hołyszewski's law: Every NoSQL DBMS eventually adds all functionality of an SQL DBMS in such a way that the functionality is absurdly difficult to use and to code.

Answer (score 1):

So I misread the initial question but to answer, there isn't any way of doing that query in a single query using MongoDB.

Normally when setting up data, you don't want to normalize your data like that (a separate collection for a user, their likes, and the pages).

So the first step would be getting a unique list of likes based on the user we're looking for.

```
db.likes.find({personId: <your_id>}, function(e, allLikes) {/* more */})
```

After you get the likes, you'll want to get a unique list of page ID's.  You can do that using `_.uniq()` or other methods found online.

Once you get an array of unique page `_id`s, you can now do the query using `$nin`.

```
db.pages.find({_id: { $nin: uniquePageIds } }, function(e, allUnlikedPages) { /* your logic */ })
```

`$nin` takes an array and will match anything that has a value that isn't in the array.  [You can read here for more details.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

Comment: Thanks. This kind of query will be one of the most frequent operations in my system. What would the proper way to structure the data in this case? I'm just starting to work on this, so I can design it like I want.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Normally you'll want to include related data together.  In your example we have the `user`, `likes` (separate record per like), and `pages`.  In the ideal world the likes would be included in the user information as an array, or alternatively the `likes` collection would hold one record for all the user's likes.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko If you are storing likes inside the `user` data, you might be mindful of [BSON limits within MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) (16MB size limit per record).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I search for my default company status which don't have company in it. so the query goes like if company does not exists and isDefault is true

```
`defaultStatus = await Status.findOne({ company:{$exists:false}, isDefault: true });`
```